# Names with dash does not work in django-haystack

Tags: python, django, search, django-haystack

I'm working on an application based on django 1.8 and search engine django-haystack 2.4.1.
A strange situation because when I search for the words `"New York"` - everything is OK.
When there is a strange name in the name of the event for example. `"Zo-zo on"` (with dash) search does not show correct results, only pages isolated instances of letters, for example: `"zo ..."`

I made `rebuild_index`.

```
class EventIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    text = indexes.EdgeNgramField(document=True, use_template=True)
    id = indexes.CharField(model_attr='id')
    get_absolute_url = indexes.CharField(model_attr='get_absolute_url')
    description = indexes.CharField(model_attr='description', null=True)
    is_past = indexes.CharField(model_attr='is_past', default='false')
    date_start = indexes.DateTimeField(model_attr='date_start')

    def get_model(self):
        return Booking

    def index_queryset(self, using=None):
        date_past = now() - timedelta(days=1)
        return self.get_model().published.filter(date_start__gt=date_past).filter(id=7353)

    def read_queryset(self, using=None):
        return self.get_model().all_objects.all()
```

Comment: Can you share your searchIndex schema corresponding to the same.

Comment: @BipulJain You mean code?

Comment: yes. You must have specific searchIndex search_indexes.py

Comment: please check my update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok based on your search index schema. You are using EdgeNGramField which tokenize everything that you give to it into token of size 2 and more.

For ex : if you **new york** it will tokenize and make sure your document matches to terms like **ne, new, yo, yor and york**. EdgeNGram fields are generally used for autosuggest as it during query and indexing time it tokenize the word into such forms.

You can change your schema to CharField. That way it will **zo-zo** will transform to **zo zo**  which will match to **Zo-zo on** in your index.

```
class EventIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    text = indexes.CharField(document=True, use_template=True)
```

to do a match like as you intend. It will only support exact word matches that way.

Create a seperate field if you intend to keep EdgeNGram Field.

Comment: thank you very much for your amswer. Please can you tell me how I can have CharField and EdgeNGramField in model? I need EdgeNGramField.
I tried with `text_1 = indexes.CharField(document=True, use_template=True)` but I can have only one field with `document=True`